# PascalCase or camelCase for C# attribute parameters?

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

In [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/creating-custom-attributes) Microsoft documentation, they use camelCase for the author and version parameters. But the predefined attributes uses PascalCase, see for example [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.attributeusageattribute) for the three parameters. What coding convention is most commonly used?

Comment: It's a typo in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, so I will use as usual camelCase for constructor parameters, and PascalCase for the properties of the Attribute class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either the documentation formats texts to have sentence upper case or it considers initialized properties names...

> The three properties of AttributeUsageAttribute are set by defining
> the following parameters:
>
> ```
> ValidOn
> ```

The result is the same as you can read in the documentation and you have the real syntax of parameters here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.attributeusageattribute.-ctor

Where there is:

```
public AttributeUsageAttribute (AttributeTargets validOn);
```

You should use official common coding standard as near as possible.

Sometimes you will find code that does not conform, even on MS websites.

Comment: Ok, the validOn parameter for the constructor is in camelCase. But what about the properties for the attribute class? In the Microsoft example page, the "version" property is in camelCase, but for the AttributeUsage class, the ValidOn property is in PascalCase, and the other properties like "Inherited" as well.

Comment: It's may be a little "error" on the sample page...

Comment: In that example, `version` is actually a public field. So yes, you are definitely right that even Microsoft's code may not conform to its standards